# Is there a way to config Xcode Automatic Profile Selector to certain team profile?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have several iPhone Team Provisional Profiles installed. Each time I download a project from GitHub and open in Xcode, the default profile selected is not the one I prefer.

Is there a way to make Xcode to auto-select a particular `iPhone Team Provisional Profile`?

Answer (score 0):

The auto selector works based upon the app id, ie the bundle prefix and the product name.  To make a specific one more likely to be selected, make the bundle prefix match more closely to the app id of the desired profile.

When the autoselector looks to choose a Team Provisioning Profile, which is a wildcard, I believe Xcode just selects the first that is downloaded and installed.

Unless you are creating an .ipa and distributing it, ie you are deploying only to your own app or device, then the selected team provisioning profile doesn't matter.

If you are distributing your app to be used or tested by non-developers, ie through testflight or another site, if you want a specific provisioning profile to be chosen you should provide it with more scope, ie com.companyname.testing.* and change the bundle prefix to match said scope of desired provisioning profile.